# AWS kinesis video stream in raspberrypi. Unable to create Kinesis Video stream

Tags: video-streaming, apache-camel-aws-kinesis

I'm trying to stream video from raspberry pie using aws kinesis video stream.
We used c++ sdk on the Aws site (https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp)

./kinesis_video_gstreamer_sample_app stream name

I try this.

Then there was an error with that log.

[ERROR] [19-04-2020 19:20:33:859.598 GMT] createKinesisVideoStreamSync(): Failed to create Kinesis Video Stream - timed out.

[INFO ] [19-04-2020 19:20:33:859.962 GMT] freeKinesisVideoStream(): Freeing Kinesis Video stream.

[ERROR] [19-04-2020 19:20:36:461.643 GMT]  Unable to create Kinesis Video stream. saStream Error status: 0xf

[INFO ] [19-04-2020 19:20:36:462.176 GMT] Freeing Kinesis Video Stream saStream

[INFO ] [19-04-2020 19:20:36:462.352 GMT] freeKinesisVideoStream(): Freeing Kinesis Video stream.

[ERROR] [19-04-2020 19:20:36:462.592 GMT] Failed to initialize kinesis video with an exception:  Unable to create Kinesis Video stream. savvyStream Error status: 0xf

[INFO ] [19-04-2020 19:20:36:462.817 GMT] freeKinesisVideoClient(): Freeing Kinesis Video Client

[DEBUG] [19-04-2020 19:20:36:462.939 GMT] curlApiCallbacksShutdownActiveRequests(): pActiveRequests hashtable is empty

[DEBUG] [19-04-2020 19:20:36:864.288 GMT] freeKinesisVideoClientInternal(): Total allocated memory 0

[WARN ] [19-04-2020 19:20:36:864.546 GMT] curlApiCallbacksShutdown(): curlApiCallbacksShutdown called when already in progress of shutting down

I think the connection was successful, but I the data transmission is not working. because of time out. 
I used ap-northeast-2 region.
I tried to find a solution, but it was hard.
please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As the logs indicate, you are timing out trying to create the stream (the sample uses the sync version of the create API) so no data is transmitted. By default, the logger log level is debug so you should be able to see the root cause (could be a number of reasons, including auth and/or networking). Please include the full log to understand what's going on.

You will get a lot quicker response if you file an issue in the GitHub repository for the project.

Comment: Thank you. It was very helpful.